# Why doesn't the bind() work for a function inside another function which is inside the object?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have a question about .bind() function. 
I have this code and it outputs Window object and I don't understand why. Could you explain to me why bind(this) had no effect on the function?

```
let vakho = {
    name: "salome",
    a: function () {

        let something = function () {
            return this;
        }
        something.bind(this) 

        return {
            f: function () {
                return something();
            }
        }
    },
}

console.log(vakho.a().f())
```

Comment: `something = something.bind(this) `

Comment: `something.bind(this)` returns new function, doesn't modify `something`, you better use `var newFunc = something.bind(this)` and `return newFunc()` in `f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind` returns a new function with the attached context. You need to assign the result to the `something` again.

```js
let vakho = {
    name: "salome",
    a: function () {

        let something = function () {
            return this;
        };
        
        something = something.bind(this); // Assign to the something

        return {
            f: function () {
                return something();
            }
        }
    },
}

console.log(vakho.a().f());
console.log(vakho.a().f().name);
```

Comment: Or just `let something = function () {
            return this;
        }.bind(this);`

Comment: Oh my lord :( Thanks guys.